# It's possible to use Miracast with a Moto G5 Plus and Android H96 Pro TV box?

Tags: motorola-moto-g5, miracast, h96-pro+

I'm trying to connect my Moto G5 Plus phone to my new H96 Pro+ tv box without success.

I connect both to the same network but can't transmit screen. It simply won't appear as a device in Miracast.

Is this a problem with Moto G5 that doesn't have this feature or there is any workaround ?

Comment: Can you try casting from within an app, like Netflix or Youtube?